# WepApi 2 Odata Controller Post/Put Relationsips/Link/Refs with Switch Statement

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api2, odata, navigation-properties

Using OData V3(#ref) or V4(#links) with in WebApi 2+ Controller and handling relationships:

**Are Switch Statements the only way?**

These 2 resources for each seem to indicate the necessity of a switch case for each navigation property.

- [Entity Relations in OData V3](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/working-with-entity-relations)
- [Entity Relations in OData V4](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4)

  ```
  switch (navigationProperty)
  {
      case "Supplier":
          // Note: The code for GetKeyFromUri is shown later in this topic.
          var relatedKey = Helpers.GetKeyFromUri<int>(Request, link);
          var supplier = await db.Suppliers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == relatedKey);
          if (supplier == null)
          {
              return NotFound();
          }

          product.Supplier = supplier;
          break;

      default:
          return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
  }
  ```

Question:  Am I supposed to hard code a switch statement for each navigation property, and if so, is there a way to have this auto-magically scaffold?

Comment: Please add sample code and/or include an example scenario

Comment: Added code sample from links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the problem like this (v4), and I solved it by using the base controller [example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fe97977150b53d542377c32edf66185d). There are 2 base controllers: for navigation (your case) and the CRUD operations - the 3th is example of usage. The code is not so clean (I have been trying to remove unnecessary details) but I think the idea is pretty clear. I do not think that it is a best way to solve this problem, but I have not found any simpler way to add and delete properties by string. I would like to know more elegant answer. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this and create the GitHubGist.  I like your solution.  And, your are answering a stackOverflow question in a foreign(to you) language.  Nothing to apologize for.